# Run a cron job every minute only on specific hours?

Tags: php, cron, centos

How do you run a cron job every minute only on specific hours? Like so:

> It will only check every minute from 11AM to 12AM, 4PM to 5PM and 9PM to 10PM

It seems to be complicated to me I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Right solution:

```
* 11,16,21 * * *
```

Because if you use previous solution:

```
0-59 11-12,16-17,21-22 * * * *
```

Job will start at 12:40 or 17:59. It is not in range from 11AM to 12AM, 4PM to 5PM and 9PM to 10PM.

**UPDATE:**

Traditional (inherited from Unix) cron format consists of five fields separated by white spaces:

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 is Sunday, or use names)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

[nnCron](http://www.nncron.ru/) can use both traditional and "enhanced" version of cron format, which has an additional (6th) field: Year.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [cron format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm)

```
<Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_the_Month> <Month_of_the_Year> <Day_of_the_Week> <Year>

* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

the solution should be

```
* 11,16,21 * * * *
```