# How to express every 5 minut from 8 to 9.30?

Tags: cronexpression

Is it possible to schedule job to run every 5 minut from 8 to 9.30 from Monday to Friday by single expression? The only thing that comes to my mind is dividing it into two parts, 8-9 and 9-9.30. Then there will by two expressions:  * */5 8 * * MON-FRI   and * 5-30/5 9 * * MON-FRI.

Comment: You might find this post helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914445/run-a-cron-job-every-minute-only-on-specific-hours

Comment: There is another case.