# Run a cron job every minute only between 10 am to 5 pm

Tags: cron

How do you run a cron job every minute only between office hours(10 am to 5pm)

I checked this thread [Run a cron job every minute only on specific hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914445/run-a-cron-job-every-minute-only-on-specific-hours) but it doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be correct:

```
* 10-16 * * 1-5 /path/to/my-script
```

So every single minute, between and including 10am and 5pm, every day in every month that is a day between and including monday to friday. Obviously "office hours" is a fuzzy expression, many people have other schedules ;-)

Unfortunately I fail to see an easy solution to get the script executed also exactly on 5pm...

Comment: @last sentence - the easiest solution would be to duplicate this line in crontab and change it to run only on 5:00pm ;-)

Comment: @dragoste That certainly would be possible, though not exactly elegant. I decided against, since such an execution would be running _outside_ the requested time, so I would assume it is not requested. But that is something that only the OP can decide :-) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
* 10-16 * * * /path/to/executable/file argument_1 argument_2
```

Yes, you can define hours range.

Someone tried to edit my answer but as documentation says hours in range are inclusive http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html so don't change 16 to 17.

Answer (score -1):

It does,

Access your shell script and add the following

```
  * 10-17 * * *
```

This means run every min, between these hours, on every day, of every month etc