# How to set cron every 2 minutes but only for 4 hours starting at 12:00 AM

Tags: cron

I need a cron job that start at 12:00 AM and trigger the job every 2 minutes but only until 4:00 AM.

With this command I have to triggers another cron job that is very heavy and often killed by my server, so with this command every 2 minute the server is forced to resume the job.

```
Minute  Hour    Day Month   Weekday Command Actions
*/2 0,14    *   *   *
```

Cron job every 2 minutes for 4 hours, every day, starting at 12:00 AM.

Comment: You read `man 5 crontab` I assume?  Where did you get the `0,14` entry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a cron job every minute only between 10 am to 5 pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243252/run-a-cron-job-every-minute-only-between-10-am-to-5-pm)